# A notational confusion in a Bell like inequality

Tags: entanglement

In the tripartite Bell type inequality know as Svetlichny inequality, given in this (freely available) [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.09540.pdf). The *quantity* $M_{ijk} = Tr [\rho(\sigma_i \otimes \sigma_j \otimes \sigma_k)]$, $i,j,k\in \{1,2,3 \}$, where $\sigma_i$ represents Pauli matrix, is defined below equation 6.

My question: After this *quantity*, they define the matrix  $M_{j, ik}$, but it is not clear to me how this matrix is related to $M_{ijk}$. In other words, how do I obtain $M_{j,ik}$ from $M_{ijk}$?

Comment: I guess they are *nearly* the same, $M_{ijk}$ is the element of the matrix $M$ by some manipulation of the order of the index.

Answer (score 3):

The standard meaning of this notation is that you're using $n$-ary encoding of the indices. In this case $n=3$, so
\begin{align}11 \sim 1\\
12 \sim 2 \\
13 \sim 3 \\
21 \sim 4 \\
22 \sim 5 \\
23 \sim 6 \\
31 \sim 7 \\
32 \sim 8 \\
33 \sim 9
\end{align}
The matrix element $M_{1,6}$ is then represented as $M_{1,23}$ which is given by $M_{213}$.

Comment: why $M_{j, ik}$ and not say $M_{i,jk}$?

Comment: I don't know. Write the authors, I'm sure they'll appreciate the interest.

Comment: @User101 If there are some replies, glad to know! :)

Comment: Actually I found this notation in a bunch of paper and wrote to all the authors. No replies so far! Will definitely share here if I get one.